# How do you mock IContextChannel in a WCF ServiceAuthorizationManager?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write unit tests for a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager.  The call to CheckAccessCore takes an OperationContext as a parameter.  To instantiate an OperationContext, one must pass an IContextChannel to the constructor.  Using MOQ, I've declared an IContextChannel:

```
private OperationContext _context;
private Mock<IContextChannel> _contextChannelMock;
```

Then I attempt to create the OperationContext:

```
_context = new OperationContext(_contextChannelMock.Object);
```

But this line throws an exception:

> Result Message:   Initialization method
>   Urs.EnterpriseServices.Providers.Tests.UrsServiceAuthorizationManager_Tests.SetUp
>   threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid IContextChannel passed to
>   OperationContext. Must be either a server dispatching channel or a
>   client proxy channel..

How do I mock, a server dispatching channel?

Comment: What code do you use to setup the `Object` property of your `Mock<IContextChannel>`?

Comment: None at this point.  I tried setting up each of the properties and I still got the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly. See if [WCFMock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it does not have the mock that I would need for working with a ServiceAuthorizationManager, from what I see of it.  That is unfortunate as I'd like to have testable authorization logic.

Comment: I suppose I could write a new method that uses the OperationContext wrapper, then everything would be testable.

Comment: @Steve how did You do it? I'm having the same problem.